# regex replace string with dollar sign, Weird output

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a javascript function as follows to convert an html blockquote to a markdown blockquote:

```
    function convertBlockquote(str) {
        var r = str;

        var pat = /<blockquote>\n?([\s\S]*?)\n?<\/blockquote>/mi;  //[\s\S] = dotall; ? = non-greedy match
        for (var mat; (mat = r.match(pat)) !== null; ) {
            mat = mat[1]
            .replace(/\n/gm, '\n> ')
            .replace(/<p>/igm, '\n> ')
            .replace(/<\/p>/igm, '\n> \n> ')
            .replace(/(\n> ?){3,}/gm, '\n> \n> ');
            r = r.replace(pat, '\n>' + mat + '\n');
        }
        return r;
    }
```

So if I pass in: `<blockquote>Price: $1000 plus tax.</blockquote>`
I would expect: `> Price: $1000 plus tax.`
But I get: `> Price: Price: $1000 plus tax.000 plus tax.`

Notice how it is replacing `$1` in the $1000 part of the  string with the entire original string?

How can I escape this or update the function to handle this (and other special chars which might cause similar issue)?

Comment: Are you looking [**for this**](https://regex101.com/r/nJ4tO2/1), ie getting rid of the tags ?

Comment: No, its a rudimentary way to replace certain html tags with "markdown" syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace:

> You can specify a function as the second parameter. In this case, the function will be invoked after the match has been performed. The function's result (return value) will be used as the replacement string. (Note: the above-mentioned special replacement patterns do *not* apply in this case.)

So you can write

```
r = r.replace(pat, function () { return '\n>' + mat + '\n'; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something obvious or the implementation looks complicated?

That's how I'd do that:

```
str=str.replace(/<blockquote>(.*?)<\/blockquote>/g,'> $1')
```

In case you'd like the multiline quotes to be matched:

```
str=str.replace(/<blockquote>((.|\n)*?)<\/blockquote>/g,'> $1')
```

Comment: That was a really simple example just to illustrate what was happening. This is a rudimentary function to replace a blockquote tag and it's contents with a markdown-formatted version of the contents. The additional "complication" is for handling cases other than a single line.

Comment: @robar Edited to handle newlines.